# AWS Pinpoint: How to view custom metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, mobile, analytics, amazon-cognito

It is clear from the documentation that I can add custom metrics for a custom event.

How do I view these metrics in the Pinpoint console? From the Pinpoint console, it is obvious how to view attributes. I can go to Analytics > Events, select my custom event, and narrow down the events to whatever attributes I desire. I am asking about how to view metrics. To be clear, these differ by being continuous values whereas attributes are discrete. The documentation says that I can do this. See below how I can filter by attributes manually: (attribute is circled)

[image: Image of Pinpoint console]

See the docs on custom events here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/integrate-events.html

Similarly, creating a funnel only allows filtering for attributes. How can I filter for metrics?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I first asked this question, AWS had the ability to **record** metrics with the Swift SDK, but **not** view them in the Pinpoint API, which is absurd, because then you can only record metrics. What's the point? I asked in the AWS forums, and a couple months later, they responded something along the lines of "Please wait - coming soon."

This feature is now available, whereas before it simply wasn't.

Go to Pinpoint, your project, then click the Analytics drop-down menu, then click events. You can see that you can sort by metric. If you look at my outdated screenshot above, you'll see that this was **not** an option.

[image: Image of Pinpoint console]

Comment: I also use custom event reporting. Did you find any better way to analyze the event details?For example, import the event record to database and query it with sql.

Comment: Hopefully someone can help you - I don't know the answer because I stopped using Pinpoint @dragonfly